# Requesting deletion of a question

Tags: support, closed-questions

I would like to delete one of my questions because (1) it is closed and (2) it has been downvoted, but I am unable to do so since it had received an answer. It is found on the Linguistics SE and I have already flagged the question but no change has resulted, which brings me to ask on meta:

"*How (selecting which option) should a user [contact](https://stackoverflow.com/contact/) support for requesting deletion of a question.*"

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question

Comment: Now this question has been downvoted and I cannot delete it :(

Comment: You cannot delete this question because *already according to Ollie's link recommendation*, it's not because it's downvoted (there is already a -3 score post badge so it's an obvious prediction), it's because it has a useful answer.

Comment: Yes but I do not wish to keep it if it has been downvoted.

Comment: Then you can *flag it for moderator attention...* or edit it for further improvement for upvotes if desired.

Comment: @aitía Reaching for the delete button just because something is downvoted is against the spirit of our network, and is likely to get you blocked from posting anything in the future. You should consider looking at the questions and trying to improve them. We do not support the notion of deleting things instantly because they've been downvoted.

Comment: Or for shortening, questions are *questions*.

Comment: Ok, I understand thank you.

Comment: Please also see [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) (cc: @loan_2314 flagging it for moderator attention in order to ask for it to be deleted should be unlikely to be effective. General policy is that moderators will just decline such flags. See the "If I flag my post with a request to delete it, what will happen?" section of the answer to the question I linked here.)

Comment: See Makyen's comment above; this is answered in [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that). Also, this post is only applicable to one site, which means it's considered off-topic here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You do not. The support team does not get involved in deleting questions and will just tell you that if you cannot delete it yourself due to system restrictions, then it cannot be deleted.

Comment: Unless questions have to be *redacted*, but that's a moderator action. They don't need the support team for that and isn't done lightly. Not an option for this question anyway.

Comment: @Mast We do have separate guidance we send along if it looks like a post needs a redaction. :)